# How to report error from a Moose constructor?

Tags: perl, error-handling, moose

I have a class that reads configuration. Now the problem is that I don't know how to report errors from this class.

Using `die` isn't sufficient, since the configuration is parametric, and errors are common.

The situation is complicated by the fact, that I'm invoking the read function in `Moose` `BUILD` method. Because this usage significantly improves readability when the class is used, I would like to keep it this way.

Comment: I think you need to define "error" in order to get a useful answer to this.  An error during construction should prevent construction and so `die` is appropriate.  What non-error condition are you terming an "error" in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with `die`?  It throws an exception that you can capture and process as needed. In fact [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose) itself throws exception on validation errors.

Comment: So I should use `die` and catch it with `eval`?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be - you can catch with `eval`, but there are some corner-cases that might bite you. I am using [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny) to avoid them.  See its docs (BACKGROUND) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [Carp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Carp) for its `croak()` function.  From its documentation:

> The Carp routines are useful in your own modules because they act like
>   die() or warn(), but with a message which is more likely to be useful
>   to a user of your module. In the case of cluck, confess, and longmess
>   that context is a summary of every call in the call-stack. For a
>   shorter message you can use carp or croak which report the error as
>   being from where your module was called.

Used along with [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try%3a%3aTiny) you get a more powerful, flexible, and descriptive solution than matching good old die with eval.  You don't have to worry about the edge cases that cause $@ to provide bad information, for example.  And your exceptions can be more accurately descriptive, as well as more detailed.  With Carp, you can even make your croaks behave like confess, providing a detailed stack trace, which makes it easier to see exactly where a problem is originating.